# Can't make custom C# node working on spatial

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, webgl

I create a custom C# node to work on Spatial by using Visual Scripting. When i'm trying my node on Editor it's working but when i'm "testing active scene" to put my scene on spatial it's not working anymore. I want to know if i'm missing something or it just can't work on Spatial.

```
 using Unity.VisualScripting;
 using UnityEngine;
 
 public class ShowSceneNew : Unit
 {
     [DoNotSerialize] public ControlInput In;
 
     [DoNotSerialize] public ControlOutput Out;
 
     [DoNotSerialize] public ValueInput myLevel;
 
     [DoNotSerialize] public ValueInput myListScene;
     [DoNotSerialize] public ValueInput myListRespawn;
     [DoNotSerialize] public ValueOutput result;
     
     private GameObject resultValue;
     private GameObject respawnValue;
     private GameObject TempValue;
 
     protected override void Definition()
     {
         In = ControlInput("inputTrigger", (flow) =>
         {
             for (int i = 0; i < flow.GetValue<AotList>(myListScene).Count; i++)
             {
                 TempValue = (GameObject) flow.GetValue<AotList>(myListScene)[i];
                 TempValue.SetActive(false);
 
                 if (i == flow.GetValue<int>(myLevel))
                 {
                     resultValue = (GameObject) flow.GetValue<AotList>(myListScene)[i];
                     TempValue.SetActive(true);
                     respawnValue = (GameObject)flow.GetValue<AotList>(myListRespawn)[i];
                 }
             }
 
             return Out;
         });
         Out = ControlOutput("outputTrigger");
 
         myLevel = ValueInput<int>("myLevel");
         myListScene = ValueInput<AotList>("myListScene");
         myListRespawn = ValueInput<AotList>("myListRespawn");
         result = ValueOutput<GameObject>("result", (flow) => respawnValue);
         Requirement(myLevel,
             In); //Specifies that we need the myValueA value to be set before the node can run.
         Requirement(myListScene,
             In); //Specifies that we need the myValueB value to be set before the node can run.
         Succession(In,
             Out); //Specifies that the input trigger port's input exits at the output trigger port. Not setting your succession also dims connected nodes, but the execution still completes.
     }
 }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is spatial?

Comment: spatial.io . Meta stuff where you can import your unity scene on web by webgl.

Comment: Could you fix this?